# apache spark DataFrame Operations reading json file

Tags: scala, search, apache-spark, cpu-word

I am trying search word on spark . First, I create sql context

```
scala> val sqlcontext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
```

Then I created a json file and kept in the scala path

```
{
   {"id" : "1201", "name" : "satish", "age" : "25"}
   {"id" : "1202", "name" : "krishna", "age" : "28"}
   {"id" : "1203", "name" : "amith", "age" : "39"}
   {"id" : "1204", "name" : "javed", "age" : "23"}
   {"id" : "1205", "name" : "prudvi", "age" : "23"}
}
```

Got error when I type this

```
scala> val dfs = sqlContext.read.json("employee.json")
```

Error

```
dfs: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_corrupt_record: string, age: string, id: string, name: string]
```

Comment: a) Spark JSON reader supports JSON line format not multiline JSON b) This is not even valid JSON

Comment: @zero323 so what should i need to do ???

Comment: For starters drop the first left bracket and the last right bracket.

Comment: @zero323 hey thank you sir. again there is a problem when i tried to show the data . dfs.show() its says<console>:22: error: object > is not a member of package scala
              scala > dfs.show()
                    ^
any help sir

Comment: Some version mismatch?

Comment: @zero323 no its same ..i can see individual data like from age, name and id but cant see one full data .. anyways thank you sir .. spark is interesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An array of people in JSON would look something like:

```
{ "people": [
    {"id" : "1201", "name" : "satish", "age" : "25"},
    {"id" : "1202", "name" : "krishna", "age" : "28"},
    {"id" : "1203", "name" : "amith", "age" : "39"},
    {"id" : "1204", "name" : "javed", "age" : "23"},
    {"id" : "1205", "name" : "prudvi", "age" : "23"}
  ]
}
```

If you want one json value per line, as spark would require, you'd want something more like:

```
    {"id" : "1201", "name" : "satish", "age" : "25"}
    {"id" : "1202", "name" : "krishna", "age" : "28"}
    {"id" : "1203", "name" : "amith", "age" : "39"}
    {"id" : "1204", "name" : "javed", "age" : "23"}
    {"id" : "1205", "name" : "prudvi", "age" : "23"}
```

In this second case, each line is one valid json document.  In the former case the entire thing is a valid json document.  In your case you don't have either.  There are tools that will validate json, e.g. you could try parsing the json in a javascript console window in chrome developer tools.

From a data modelling perspective you would typically also want age to be represented as a birth date instead of the transient current age... or at least to be numeric instead of a string.